# Getting Started Web service and RestFul API Testing with CUCUMBER - Looking for tutorials

Tags: automated-testing, ruby, cucumber

I am looking to get started building a project and want to use CUCUMBER from day one. My Ruby background is Intermediate; however, I do have a good understanding of MVC and the structure within Ruby.

In doing some research for books and tutorials, I am not finding any good resource or tutorial  to start.

Answer (score 3):

Have you seen these? I did a search in google for: "rest testing with ruby"

- [How to test a JSON REST API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13955233/how-to-test-a-json-rest-api)
- [REST API test cucumber steps best practise](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16741490/rest-api-test-cucumber-steps-best-practise)

On the other hand, if you have Ruby skills, then you can write your own library to deal with REST responses or you can use something from [RubyGems](http://rubygems.org/).

Answer (score 1):

Chapter 12 of [The Cucumber Book](http://pragprog.com/book/hwcuc/the-cucumber-book) deals with testing REST Web Services, as well as a wealth of useful advice on getting started with Cucumber in general. The chapter walks through two different approaches. Whether you decide to use the same tools or not, I think the techniques are useful.

The team I work in decided to write our own library, but as SayusiAndo points out, there are a number of gems too for dealing with REST responses.